# Seats reservation is open vs Seats registration is open

Tags: word-choice, word-request

If we are going to announce admissions in the coming days and we haven't announced yet, which Slogan will be proper to use in a footer? Reservation or registration?

Comment: You should look up *reservation* or *registration* in a dictionary. They mean different things, and either could apply to your situation.

Comment: "**Reserve** your seat now!", "**Reserve** your place..." or "**Register** to attend our..."

Answer (score 2):

I would use 'Seating registration is now open', or more plainly put, 'We are now accepting reservations for seating'.